# Django - How to only save form to database if a specific field is NOT filled out (honeypot trap for signup spam)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have recently been having some trouble with fake signups on my website signup form. I've decided the best way to deal with this is to create an 'invisible' honeypot form field.

I have created this new 'fake' form field in my models.py and forms.py, I have rendered the field in my template, and I have hidden the field from real users using 'display: none' in my CSS. What I want to be able to do now is only save the form to the database if the 'fake' field is NOT filled out.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
    if form.is_valid() and fakeformfield.is_null():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('thankyou')
```

If you need to see my code just say and I will update the question.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the issue you faced here?

Comment: Highly recommend just using a captcha... more robust solution even if it's slightly annoying at times. There are plenty of django captcha integration libs

Comment: @PeteTinkler Thanks for your comment. I'm not that fond of captcha purely for UX reasons. Just a quick question, if Captcha can prevent, say, 95% of fake signups, what % would you say the honeypot method can prevent?

Comment: I don't have exact numbers but I would have thought Captcha prevents far more than 95% of fake signups.. It would take highly specialised OCR to get through them. Whereas your honeypot will only catch bots that use a "fill in every field in the html and press submit" which I suspect is a low amount. It's an interesting experiment (that I'd like to see the results for) but not, I think, robust :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if form.is_valid():
    fake_field_value = form.cleaned_data.get('fakeformfield')
    if not fake_field_value:
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
return redirect('thankyou')
```

This would give what you are looking for. But i am not sure how could it prevent the fake submissions. If it is somebody trying to do it using a crawler, he can simply see that this field is hidden and would avoid filling the value. Consider using a captcha.

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for your response. Isn't this quite an established method of preventing fake signups? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here is a short article about honeypots: https://blog.loginradius.com/2015/02/stop-spam-signups/ Check out number 4

Comment: This could prevent some. But if somebody wants to actually target your form, there are still ways to bypass it.

Comment: Sandeep, do you think it would be a better idea to let the robot submit the form with the 'fake' field filled out and then manually remove the fake signups in my database?

Comment: In order to be more effective, you should always `return redirect('thankyou')` regardless of whether or not the honeypot field was filled.